# Mongoose Find All Documents Matching a Substring of Inputs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, tagging

Suppose you have this array of `fileNames`:

```
[
    'filename1_c4d.rar',
    'text122_octane.c4d',
    'texture1.png',
    'texture2.png',
]
```

And in my database I have a collection of `Tags`:

```
[
    {
        _id: 'id1',
        name: 'cinema4d',
        aliases: ['.c4d', 'c4d', 'cinema4d'],
    },
    {
        _id: 'id2',
        name: 'octane',
        aliases: ['octane'],
    },
    {
        _id: 'id3',
        name: 'textures',
        aliases: ['texture', 'textures'],
    },
    // ...
]
```

My goal is to fetch all `Tags` that have a substring of my `fileNames` in `aliases`, with the help of `mongoose`. (`Tags.find({ someFancyQuery: fileNames })`)

---

Here is an example to make it better understandable:

I have this fileName: `filename1_c4d.rar`. Based on this name the query should be able to fetch the `Tag` with the name `cinema4d`, because it's aliases include a substring of the fileName `filename1_`**`c4d`**`.rar`

So those fileNames should fetch the following `Tags`:

- `filename1_`**`c4d`**`.rar` ➔ `cinema4d`
- `text122_`**`octane`**`.`**`c4d`** ➔ `cinema4d, octane`
- **`texture`**`1.png` ➔ `textures`
- **`texture`**`2.png` ➔ `textures`

---

So in the end the result of the query should be those `Tags` (without duplicated):

`cinema4d, octane, textures`

---

P.S.: To explain what this is for:

A user can upload e.g. a `.rar` file and I want to automatically assign tags based on the filenames, that are inside the `.rar` file.

---

I hope it's clear what my goal is. Please let me know if there is somewthing you don't understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use aggregation pipeline to compare alias is substring of input array

```
db.t5.aggregate([
        {$addFields :{tags: tags, matches : {$map:{input: "$aliases", as: "a", in: {$map : {input: tags, as: "i", in: {$gte:[{$indexOfCP:["$$i", "$$a"]},0]}}}}}}}, 
        {$addFields: {matchez :{$reduce : {input : "$matches", initialValue : [], in: { $concatArrays: [ "$$value", "$$this" ] }}}}}, 
        {$match: {"matchez" : {$in : [true]}}}, 
        {$group : {_id: null, names : {$addToSet : "$name"}}}
    ])
```

result

```
{ "_id" : null, "names" : [ "octane", "textures", "cinema4d" ] }
```

sample collection

```
> db.t5.find()
{ "_id" : "id1", "name" : "cinema4d", "aliases" : [ ".c4d", "c4d", "cinema4d" ] }
{ "_id" : "id2", "name" : "octane", "aliases" : [ "octane" ] }
{ "_id" : "id3", "name" : "textures", "aliases" : [ "texture", "textures" ] }
{ "_id" : "id4" }
{ "_id" : "id5" }
{ "_id" : "id6" }
```

input tags

```
> tags
[
        "filename1_c4d.rar",
        "text122_octane.c4d",
        "texture1.png",
        "texture2.png"
]
```

result

```
> db.t5.aggregate([{$addFields :{tags: tags, matches : {$map:{input: "$aliases", as: "a", in: {$map : {input: tags, as: "i", in: {$gte:[{$indexOfCP:["$$i", "$$a"]},0]}}}}}}}, {$addFields: {matchez :{$reduce : {input : "$matches", initialValue : [], in: { $concatArrays: [ "$$value", "$$this" ] }}}}}, {$match: {"matchez" : {$in : [true]}}}, {$group : {_id: null, names : {$addToSet : "$name"}}}])
{ "_id" : null, "names" : [ "octane", "textures", "cinema4d" ] }
>
```